# stream_publish using old FB api

Tags: php, facebook

I can't seem to get the stream_publish to work from the old API. I am using the old API because there is no option to upgrade with the current client.

```
$facebook->api_client->stream_publish("Test",null,null,$uid,$appid);
```

I get error 500 returned.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're calling the method properly.

Here's what the argument signature looks should look like

```
  /**
   * Publish a post to the user's stream.
   *
   * @param $message        the user's message
   * @param $attachment     the post's attachment (optional)
   * @param $action links   the post's action links (optional)
   * @param $target_id      the user on whose wall the post will be posted
   *                        (optional)
   * @param $uid            the actor (defaults to session user)
   * @return string the post id
   */
  public function stream_publish(
    $message, $attachment = null, $action_links = null, $target_id = null,
    $uid = null) {
```

But your code snippet shows `$appid` where `$uid` is expected.

Also, this wont work unless the user at `$uid` has granted [the proper permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish) to your application.